# JWT Token was removed from header when page refreshed

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I'm using Jwt token based authentication,its working fine until the page refreshed. if i press F5 the page is reloading but the token was missing

```
Host "localhost:9090"
User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Accept-Language "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate"
**Authorization "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIn…sd-ZDIpMziBmK4gq_DdmGUWbizsI"**
Referer "http://localhost:9090/fg.html"
Connection "keep-alive"
```

After refresh of the page

```
Host "localhost:9090"
    User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
    Accept "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    Accept-Language "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate"
    **Authorization "null"**
    Referer "http://localhost:9090/fg.html"
    Connection "keep-alive"
```

which creating authentication problem as the token is missing from header

in login check controller

```
responseMap.put("loginName",adminUser1.getAdminId());
responseMap.put("isUserExist",Boolean.toString(true));
responseMap.put("role",adminUser1.getPermissionGroup());
responseMap.put("session",session);
responseMap.put("balance",adminUser1.getBalance().toString());
responseMap.put("phase",phase.getPrefix());
responseMap.put("token",getToken(adminUser1.getAdminId()));
return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseMap);


public String getToken(String loginName){

        String jwtToken = "";
        final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
        Map<String, Object> headerClaims = new HashMap<>();
        headerClaims.put("typ", "JWT");

        jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(loginName)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setAudience(uuid)
                .setHeader(headerClaims)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000L))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Constants.KEY)
                .compact();

        return jwtToken;
    }
```

JwtFilter

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");


        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {

            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header");
            }

            final String token = authHeader.substring(7);

            final Claims claims;
            try {
                claims = parseClaims(Constants.KEY,token);
                request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
            } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JwtExpiredTokenException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public Claims parseClaims(String signingKey, String token) throws BadCredentialsException, JwtExpiredTokenException {
        try {
            return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(signingKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException | MalformedJwtException | IllegalArgumentException | io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException ex) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid JWT token: ");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredEx) {
            throw new JwtExpiredTokenException("JWT Token expired");
        }
    }
```

how to over come the problem, storing token in localstorage might create more security problem..?

Comment: Headers are part of the HTTP requests & responses and are not stored. You need to store the received token in client side using a cookie or localStorage, and attach it to each outgoing request using, in your case, the "Authorization" header

Comment: that's true, but i worry about security issues like  cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, how we can setup secure cookie ??

Comment: localStorage are vulnerable to XSS attacks, cookies are vulnerable to CSRF. Any technique has their own drawback. See [this](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/). You would need to add extra security measures. And, of course, use HTTPS. I suggest you to solve first the programming issue